# Where can I find drivers for Windows 7 on an iMac without Boot Camp Assistant?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, driver, efi

I have OS X installed on my 27" iMac and want to dual boot with Windows 7. I installed rEFit and then installed Windows 7. Now I need the drivers that normally get installed with Boot Camp Assistant. Does anybody know where to find them? I can't find them on Apple's site.

Comment: For more recent BootCamp versions there's http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24118/how-to-download-bootcamp-drivers-without-bootcamp-assistant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are on one of the installation disks that comes with your iMac. Also, I'm pretty sure the drivers get installed if you download and run a "[Bootcamp Software Update for Windows](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1442)"  from Apple's support site. They are usually 200MB or up downloads that come packed with drivers for windows, so give it a try in case you can't find your cds.

Comment: I found them on the Apple Disc, but the software updater did not work! :)

Comment: It would be nice with a download though, but i dont think it exists

Comment: Well, the link I posted takes you to the download in Apple's support page :) I suggest you give it a try :P

Answer (score 0):

They should be on the installer file for Windows that is linked on this [Apple Support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1443). If your Windows is 64-bit, then check out [this article](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1442). Hope this helps.