# Can’t reboot into OS X from Boot Camp

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, partition

I made a partition with Boot Camp on my wife's Macbook Pro and installed Windows, however after being installed I can not find the Boot Camp control panel.

I have looked in the control panel and the task bar. The program is simply not there. I can't get the Macbook to run OS X at all at this point, but can verify that the partition is only 40 GB in size. At this point, I don't care if I can get the partition working. I'm more worried about getting the OS X partition back up. I do not have a OS X install disk — the computer didn't come with one.

Answer (score 7):

First you should be able to boot into OS X if you press and hold the <kbd>⌥</kbd> key just after pressing the power button.

For the Bootcamp control panel to appear, you should install the Bootcamp drivers from Apple. Run *Boot Camp Assistant* to get them or try [these tips](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24118/how-to-download-bootcamp-drivers-without-bootcamp-assistant).

Also: [More on Boot Camp](http://www.apple.com/support/bootcamp/).

Comment: I guess @iskra would be delighted if you would mark his answer with the little green arrow.

Comment: Yes I'll be happy like nobody)

Comment: @alex it's the `Option` key on a Mac keyboard or `Alt` on a Windows-style keyboard.