# Can't update Boot Camp in Windows 7 (MacbookPro9,1)

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, software-update

I've been looking for situations similar to these before posting, but failed to find any. When trying to install Windows 7 (64bit) through Boot Camp Assistant on Lion, the Windows Support Software download failed. Thus, I followed the instructions from [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24118/how-to-download-bootcamp-drivers-without-bootcamp-assistant%20this) and from this [cafe-encounter.net page](http://www.cafe-encounter.net/p682/download-bootcamp-drivers-inc-mountain-lion-inc-2012-retina-display) and downloaded the suitable package for my model (MacBookPro9,1). I then installed the package and all the drivers seem to be working properly. The problem is that now I can't install the 3.1 (and consequently the 3.2) Boot Camp updates available from Apple Downloads website.

When trying to run the update, an error message stops me from proceeding:

"The Boot Camp 3.1 Update requires Boot Camp 3.0 or greater. Please install Boot Camp 3.0 before proceeding with the install of the 3.1 Update."

I thought that maybe the Boot Camp version I just downloaded is the most recent one. But if that's the case, shouldn't the message be different? And if that's not it, then I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my first guess was right, the WindowsSupport.dmg downloaded from the post's links installed Boot Camp 4.0.0.1. I just checked the details tab on the Bootcamp executable (*Program Files\Boot Camp*), didn't think of that before.

Nonetheless, I still believe the updates should be prepared to check for more recent versions and throw a different message.

Comment: Ah, error messages - the last thing a software developer pays attention to. I'm glad the links on the cafe-encounter site worked okay. BootCamp is now on version 5, I update the links again last week.