# Windows 10 Bootcamp Drivers problems

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, driver

I have a Macbook Pro from late 2011 with a failing hard drive that had macOS and Windows 7 installed on it. I just bought a new one and decided to put in a Windows 10 USB to boot from since I never used macOS that often anymore. Once I got everything setup there were no drivers (which was expected), so I downloaded them from the Bootcamp Assistant tool on a friends computer. When I try and launch the drivers setup.exe I get the error "This version of Bootcamp is not intended for this computer model". Is there any way to bypass this error or should I download the drivers from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

The Answer from Tomothy Sutton should help you with your issue

- [How to download Bootcamp drivers without Bootcamp assistant?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24118/how-to-download-bootcamp-drivers-without-bootcamp-assistant#235324)
- A list of what download you need: https://support.apple.com/de-ch/HT204048