# Unable to download the newest bootcamp drivers for my windows partition

Tags: bootcamp, windows, error

Bootcamp assistant is giving me this error :

The Startup disk must be formatted as a single mac OS Extended (Journaled) volume or already partitioned by Boot Camp Assistant for installing Windows.

I’m trying to update the boot camp drivers for my MacBook Pro 2018 running Mojave and Windows 10. I’m trying to follow the instructions to update the bootcamp drivers for my windows side. Hitting the above error when trying to download the new software. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Updating any drivers for Windows 10 can be accomplished through the following methods.

- While booted to Windows, run Apple Software Update.
- While booted to Windows, run Windows Update.
- While booted to macOS, run the Boot Camp Assistant. Look for `Download Windows Support Software` under `Action` on the menu bar. Copy the files to a FAT32 or ExFAT formatted flash drive. Boot to Windows and run the `setup` application in the `BootCamp` folder.
- Download the Windows Support Software directly from Apple. The procedure is outlined in [Chris F Carroll's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24118/how-to-download-bootcamp-drivers-without-bootcamp-assistant/59079#59079). Unfortunately, your question does not provide enough information to determine which PKG file to download.