# Does Apple offer a page that lists all versions of published Boot Camp drivers?

Tags: bootcamp

I realise that the recommended way of obtaining the latest drivers for Boot Camp is via Apple's official Boot Camp Assistant built into macOS, but was wondering if Apple offers an official index that can be used to easily obtain archival versions of the drivers that have been posted to the Apple website. Some simple searching has allowed me to find several different versions - through Boot Camp 2 to version 5, but as far as I can see, there's no "Boot Camp Downloads" page or similar from where these can all be found in a simple list.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of [How to download Bootcamp drivers without Bootcamp assistant?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24118/how-to-download-bootcamp-drivers-without-bootcamp-assistant) so you should look at [brigadier](https://github.com/timsutton/brigadier).

Comment: Many Macs have more than one version of the Window Support Software available for download from Apple. Brigadier will download only one version, which many not be the most current version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note: A version of this answer, which downloads and extracts the Boot Camp Support Software using a Windows machine, is given [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376937/is-there-an-easy-way-to-obtain-all-of-the-boot-camp-drivers-hosted-by-apple-by-u/376944#376944).

There used to be an Apple webpage which provided a table containing information needed to obtain the correct Boot Camp Support Software (Windows Support Software) for the each version of Windows officially supported for a given Mac. The information was either a link to a webpage where the correct Boot Camp Support Software could be downloaded or the name of the DVD containing the desired software. Basically, the DVD was the Snow Leopard installation DVD. Currently, this webpage has be replaced with the [Install Windows 7 on your Mac using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016) webpage.

The Snow Leopard DVD contains legacy Boot Camp Support Software for XP SP2 and Vista installations. To access the Boot Camp Support Software on the Snow Leopard DVD, you need to be running Windows. I can no longer find the link where you could purchase a Snow Leopard DVD from Apple. However, a Snow Leopard ISO containing the Boot Camp Support Software can be downloaded. See this [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/363738/macos-wont-boot-into-recovery-mode-need-to-reset-admin-password/363745#363745) for more information. Again, you will need to Windows to mount and access the Boot Camp Support Software.

The accepted answer to [How to download Bootcamp drivers without Bootcamp assistant?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24118/how-to-download-bootcamp-drivers-without-bootcamp-assistant) explains how to download versions of the Boot Camp Support Software (Windows Support Software) for a particular Mac. However, the answer does not explain how to determine the differences between the available versions. Below is a script which automates steps 1 through 8 given in the answer.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#

if [[ $0 != "$BASH_SOURCE" ]]; then
    bash "$BASH_SOURCE" "$@"
    return
fi

GetPkgUrl() {
    local "sucatalog=index-10.11-10.10-10.9-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog"
    local "verbose=true"
    if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "usage: $0 [--clean] [--legacy] [--quiet] model_identifier"
        return "1"
    fi
    while :; do
        case ${1:-} in
        --clean) rm -f *.sucatalog *.dist;;
        --legacy) sucatalog="index-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog";;
        --quiet) verbose=false;;
        *) break
        esac
        shift
    done
    if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "$0: missing model identifier" >&2
        return "1"
    elif [[ $1 == -* ]]; then
        echo "$0: bad option: $1" >&2
        return "1"
    elif [[ $# -ne 1 ]]; then
        echo "$0: too many parameters"
        return "1"
    fi
    local 'sucatalogUrl=http://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/'"$sucatalog"
    local "language=English" "identifier=$1"
    shift
    if [[ ! -e $sucatalog ]]; then
        $verbose && echo "fetching $sucatalogUrl"
        curl -O "$sucatalogUrl" 2>/dev/null
    fi
    local "matches=$(grep -e "BootCampESD.pkg" -e ".$language.dist" "$sucatalog")"
    local "pkgUrl" "dist" "distUrl" 
    local -i "i" "count=0"
    local -a "dists=()" "pkgUrls=()"

    while read "pkgUrl"; do
        if [[ $pkgUrl == *BootCampESD.pkg* ]]; then
#           echo "$pkgUrl"
            read "distUrl"
            distUrl="${distUrl#*<string>}"
            distUrl="${distUrl%</string>*}"
#           echo "$distUrl"
            if [[ ! $distUrl == *"$language.dist"* ]]; then
                echo "Error: URL '$distUrl' did not contain the string '$language.dist'" >&2
                continue # exit "1"
            fi
            dist="${distUrl##*/}"
            dists+=("$dist")
            pkgUrl="${pkgUrl#*<string>}"
            pkgUrl="${pkgUrl%</string>*}"
            pkgUrls+=("$pkgUrl")
            if [[ ! -e "$dist" ]]; then
                $verbose && echo "fetching $distUrl"
                curl -O "$distUrl" 2>/dev/null
            else
                : # echo "have $distUrl"
            fi
            count="count + 1"
        fi
    done <<< "$matches"
#   echo "found $count .dist files"

    echo
    echo "Matching URL's are listed below."
    for ((i=0; i<${#dists[@]}; ++i)); do
        dist="${dists[i]}"
        if grep "'$identifier'" "$dist" >/dev/null; then
            echo "${pkgUrls[i]}"
        fi
    done
    echo
}

GetPkgUrl "$@"
```

An anonymous edit was made to this answer, where the variable `sucatalog` was changed from `index-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog` to `index-10.11-10.10-10.9-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog`.

> Note: The `--legacy` option substitutes the original file name.

The identifier of my iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2011) is `iMac12,1`. Assuming the script has already been saved to the file `getpkgurl`, the following command can be used to get a list of available downloads.

> Note: The `--clean` option removes all previous downloaded files.

```
./getpkgurl --clean --legacy iMac12,1
```

> Note: A good reference for older Mac computer to identifier translations is given [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201518).

The output from the command is given below.

> Note: The `--quiet` option can be used to remove all the `fetching` messages from the output.

```
fetching http://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/24/46/041-91737-A_KOBGOTCIEZ/0b9gnebg3ivdfsd79simxpr60vvx9sy31k/041-91737.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/26/37/041-91736-A_6XKJ6AQL4K/9qene91xdcr1ytzik312zjmbaxyujy0p7j/041-91736.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/24/21/041-88430-A_MH044N1M88/l1tfz2ccakcy7ko79ugzcw0naadra581o3/041-88430.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/62/58/041-98143-A_HN8B941A1T/nknv1gt3xcgylggwc11kl5e0j4296tjfo1/041-98143.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/63/48/041-88436-A_A9JD5TGYOC/9qwbctjgtpqblqv40gl7uwf625j5pe796i/041-88436.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/53/33/041-88396-A_YLDCG32JBG/ehs3p0jphqr5sfk0wh15gqxkua7nndzk8u/041-88396.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/28/47/041-88734-A_Q0SKN07BL0/7knxzec1xmojr5x5t7xnu5a4u6lslmlf9v/041-88734.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/25/38/041-88737-A_IXJZSM8OLV/fq3xy3duoq3xqp9o2sa8dkjtz5wvjaojhq/041-88737.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/09/31/041-88738-A_WMEMEM44HQ/hox9b0vuev029dtitorkp40rsgjdnww4qm/041-88738.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/53/06/041-88735-A_5MC8H30E1T/uzofvyg87dqhkn2qh1ipxy4f1uxduhitsb/041-88735.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/24/61/041-88748/z2zwt4m9xtxt5sf64w9v5bz760cohxc2jc/041-88748.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/36/49/041-98163/n3zau0xy5j0a121vnvud3jac2ahplizknu/BootCampESD.dst/041-98163.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/63/06/041-88804/p3d1dt0il8vi5w3wrzepvrs3992dtmkfwb/041-88804.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/57/55/041-88815/dmx4z5azm5wktzh9qh8kiyrbz874wj9h4d/041-88815.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/47/29/041-89072-A_HZY5QI4LGV/knck1r3qmsw9nliisjjm7vll0zv1u239eu/041-89072.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/32/09/041-89042-A_XVZ2U8XKG2/06ub1qfep6wv3g8bb68smwt3ac25xyng83/041-89042.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/52/10/061-26579-A_7RJL96VW4I/z662ygc05hfe7cukb3itfbc8i1j7boxu95/061-26579.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/35/46/041-87995-A_EWCD1K4CH1/2b5jaj1p2oxqlpzgwat4bdqjpjs8n3mxip/BootCampESD.dst/041-87995.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/23/15/041-91731-A_LBI7Q8UWOG/juk1ng0hm623gxh3jv4qxt190ga1h5p0lw/041-91731.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/35/26/041-88148-A_FV1FQ1MLRG/qyueop2fculv8o6ybt2oq266qo98pqphb9/041-88148.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/41/45/061-26565-A_30YFW2NOY7/mcryv1yqxl8bmiok36kl4tiycf3g72uda5/061-26565.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/04/44/041-84708/yq9w47gthzu8e8fqmad6hx0vs15fuk4540/041-84708.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/45/20/041-85204-A_24VIQ2D28M/3ln1dqstqacwzknssu2fyu3rqhf3y3b94n/BootCampESD.dst/041-85204.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/05/20/041-85201-A_6JI09ZIRDD/sma4jd483vqdug5bqoemfohvvahjd4rewx/BootCampESD.dst/041-85201.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/26/08/041-84821-A_AMCFPC3QDK/4fffs8qgdflw7pn1finqqd40gifh41mvs6/041-84821.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/57/55/041-84868-A_402D0DFI39/6uz8hhgtd4b87t00mrq0uihiop5ivumsbk/BootCampESD.dst/041-84868.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/29/62/041-84859-A_GGUOSJMIGN/sb1apxcjpp358ze2df6bzhwd49m2cqyzy5/BootCampESD.dst/041-84859.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/50/29/041-84869-A_EJ35WAWA75/obofx71e3kcf8aqzukdrzg7hqpv1p06hca/BootCampESD.dst/041-84869.English.dist
fetching http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/25/34/041-93123-A_M7QYPDZ8WH/dhg7w8ixxzaoay8anu1922grngi1sckdbn/041-93123.English.dist

Matching URL's are listed below.
http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/04/44/041-84708/yq9w47gthzu8e8fqmad6hx0vs15fuk4540/BootCampESD.pkg
http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/45/20/041-85204-A_24VIQ2D28M/3ln1dqstqacwzknssu2fyu3rqhf3y3b94n/BootCampESD.pkg
http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/26/08/041-84821-A_AMCFPC3QDK/4fffs8qgdflw7pn1finqqd40gifh41mvs6/BootCampESD.pkg
http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/57/55/041-84868-A_402D0DFI39/6uz8hhgtd4b87t00mrq0uihiop5ivumsbk/BootCampESD.pkg
```

The results show there are 4 possible URL's. Entering each URL in Safari will cause a version of the Boot Camp Support Software to download. The correct download would have to be determined by inspection.

> Note: By default, the `.pkg` installer places a `.dmg` file in the `"/Library/Application Support/BootCamp"` folder. The `.dmg` file contains the Windows Support Software.

This script was tested using `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)`. The version of macOS was High Sierra 10.13.6.

> Hint: You can paste the function `GetPkgUrl` into a Terminal application window running BASH instead of creating a script file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can find a detailed list of BootCamp support software, by year and trimester, on the following Apple link. packages are on ZIP format ready to deploy on Windows.

https://support.apple.com/en_US/downloads/BootCamp

O Digiex.net website you can find a download link for version 6 of the bootcamp drivers in one standalone 1.1Gb file.

https://digiex.net/threads/apple-windows-10-bootcamp-6-drivers-download-applebcupdate-exe-april-1st-2016.14828/

This is a download of the Windows 10 Bootcamp 6 drivers, compatible with the following Macs:

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014)
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013)
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013)
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013)
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2013)
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2012)
- MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012)
- MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012)
- MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2012)
- MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015)
- MacBook Air (11-inch, Early 2015)
- MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2014)
- MacBook Air (11-inch, Early 2014)
- MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2013)
- MacBook Air (11-inch, Mid 2013)
- MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2012)
- MacBook Air (11-inch, Mid 2012)
- MacBook (Retina, 12-inch, Early 2015)
- iMac (Retina 5k, 27-inch, Mid 2015)
- iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2014)
- iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2014)
- iMac (27-inch, Late 2013)
- iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2013)
- iMac (27-inch, Late 2012)
- iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2012)
- Mac mini (Late 2014)
- Mac mini Server (Late 2012)
- Mac mini (Late 2012)
- Mac Pro (Late 2013)

here's the direct download link
https://download.digiex.net/Drivers/Bootcamp/AppleBcUpdate6.0.6171-01.April.2016.zip