# Downloading Windows 10 64bit Boot Camp Drivers on M1 Mac

Tags: bootcamp

I'm trying to find the 64bit drivers for Boot Camp. Really only trying to get a Magic Mouse working on a Windows machine that I'm forced to use, but my only Mac now is an M1 and it won't launch Boot Camp Assistant to create the driver image.

What can I do to download them?

Comment: Perhaps a Windows-compatible Bluetooth mouse would suffice instead of jumping through hoops to get a driver which may not exist?

Comment: @IconDaemon Perhaps. I looked around for a mouse with a touchpad on top to scroll with and found that I already owned one. Reduce, reuse, recycle... ♻️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While downloading the Windows Support Software (formally the Boot Camp Support Software) should be possible for any Intel based Mac from a M1 Mac, you would first have to at least know which Intel Mac and possibly which version of Windows.

According to [everyman.com](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i5-3.3-27-inch-aluminum-retina-5k-mid-2015-specs.html) an Apple iMac 27-Inch "Core i5" 3.3 (5K, Mid-2015) has the Model Identifier `iMac15,1`. According to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP718?locale=en_US) this model had the Magic Mouse option. [AFAIK](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376915/does-apple-offer-a-page-that-lists-all-versions-of-published-boot-camp-drivers/376921#376921), the only Windows Support Software download available from Apple for an `iMac15,1` is from this [link](http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/62/58/041-98143-A_HN8B941A1T/nknv1gt3xcgylggwc11kl5e0j4296tjfo1/BootCampESD.pkg). This installs to the `/Library/Application\ Support/BootCamp` folder. The download contains over 2700 items. I found a `AppleWirelessMouse64.exe` that might be helpful.